# Django Rest Framework ModelSerializer create if not exists

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework 3.6.3.  I'm trying to write nested create serializers for one optional argument and one required argument inside a child.  I know that I need to override create in the base serializer to tell DRF how to create the nested children - http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers.

However, I can't figure out how to get it to parse the object information without telling it what the nested child serializer is defined as.  Doing that then causes DRF to use it to parse the children objects, which then returns a validation error that I have no control over because the child serializer doesn't call its create method.

- Base

  - Specification(many=True)

    - OptionalField
    - RequiredField

The information I pass in is a JSON object:

```
{ 
  base_id: 1, 
  base_info: 'blah'
  specifications: [
     { 
        specification_id: 1,
        optional_info: {
            optional_id: 1,
            optional_stuff: 'blah'
        },
        required_info: {
            required_id: 1,

required_stuff: 'required',
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

The BaseCreationSerializer calls it's create method.  I know that I need to pull out the rest of the information and create it manually.  However, I can't figure out how to get the BaseCreationSerializer to parse the data into validated_data without defining `specification = SpecificationCreationSerializer()`, which then tries to parse that and throws an error. Printing `self` shows the entire JSON object in `data`, but then `validated_data` only contains the subset of things that the serializer knows about.  How do I parse the appropriate things from `data` so that I can create the objects on my own?